# Is it possible to obtain a contradiction from provability logic GL + inference rule ($\square P$ ==> $P$)

Tags: set-theory, provability

Is it possible to obtain a contradiction from provability logic GL + inference rule ($\square P$ ==> $P$) ?

I suspect that answer is "No".

If I am right, then there is a model of such logic.

And the model is just the classical propositional logic. (i.e. all tautologies)

Because then the part of inductive definition of true(under some evaluation) modal formulas is $Truth(\square f) := Truth(f)$.

Is everything correct in the proof? (Maybe some inaccuracies?)

Does that mean, that if we have some deductive system(let it be first-order set theory), and a model of that system inside it, than we can safely add inference the rule $\square P$ ==> $P$ to the system?
(Or not necessary then, maybe, there is a finer logical connection?)

p.s. broad question: What kind of applictions adding of such extension can have? One of ideas is to prove and use, for example, the deduction theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that rule, we presumably have a theorem like:

$$
\dfrac{
  \dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{\square P ⊢ \square P}}{\square P ⊢ P}}{⊢ \square P → P}
}{
  ⊢ \square (\square P → P)
}
$$

Then:

$$
\dfrac{\dfrac{}{⊢ \square (\square P → P)} \qquad \dfrac{}{⊢ \square(\square P → P) → \square P}}{\dfrac{⊢ \square P}{⊢ P}}
$$

Comment: is it a bad idea to restrict proposed "rule" to empty contexts? Still the same problem? Or it is bad from other point of views?

Comment: That seems like it might be consistent, but I'm also not sure what the use would be.

Comment: Note the role of the deduction theorem here. If we don't add in the deduction theorem as an inference rule, we do get a consistent system since any time we can infer $\Box P$ we actually could infer $P$ as well. (Alternatively we could place the blame on necessitation.)

Answer (score 1):

There's an interesting subtlety here, around the **deduction theorem**.

Certainly accepting each sequent of the form $$\vdash \Box P\rightarrow P$$ is fatal for $\mathsf{GL}$ due to its combination with **necessitation** and **Lob's rule**. However, the sequents $$\Box P\vdash P$$ are a bit less dangerous: we only wind up with a contradiction if we *also* throw in the **deduction rule** (usually a **theorem**) as an inference rule to our new system. [Usually](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132268/deduction-theorem) the deduction theorem is rather fundamental, but this is a situation where there's a real tension between it and (a version of) the new rule under consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is true:

$\mathrm{GL}\vdash A$ $\;\Leftrightarrow\;$ $\mathrm{GL}\vdash \square A\quad$ for any modal formula $A$.

The proof is by Solovay's theorem: $\mathrm{GL}\vdash A$ iff for every realisation $*$ of the propositional variables of $A$, $\mathrm{PA}\vdash A^*$.

(In fact Solovay's theorem holds also for any elementary-recursive, $\Sigma_1$-sound theory $T$ that contains elementary arithmetic; we only need to use $\Sigma_1$-soundness here.)

Note that by $\Sigma_1$-soundness, if $\mathrm{PA}\vdash \mathrm{Prov}_{\mathrm{PA}}(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)$ where $\mathrm{Prov}_{\mathrm{PA}}$ is the PA-provability predicate, then $\mathrm{Prov}_{\mathrm{PA}}(\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)$ is true in the standard model $\mathbb{N}$, and so there exists some $y$ such that $\mathbb{N}\models \mathrm{Proof}_{\mathrm{PA}}(y,\ulcorner\phi\urcorner)$, i.e. $y$ codes a real proof of $\phi$ from PA, hence $\mathrm{PA}\vdash \phi$ by looking at the proof $y$.

Now if $\mathrm{GL}\vdash \square A$, then for all realisations $*$, $\mathrm{PA}\vdash (\square A)^*$. This implies that for all realisations $*$, $\mathrm{PA}\vdash A^*$. Thus $\mathrm{GL}\vdash A$ by Solovay.

I don't think one can apply deduction theorem arbitrarily in modal logic.